# Vue - failed to compile tiptap.esm.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I'm new to `npm` and I'm trying to use `tiptap` in my project. The problem is that after I try to import `tiptap`, it raises error. This is what I did:

- `sudo npm install -g vue-cli`
- `vue init webpack frontend`
- `vue add vuetify` - didn't do nothing so I did
- `npm add vuetify`

Then I added this to `main.js`

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

- `npm install tiptap`

Then I added `import { Editor, EditorContent } from 'tiptap'` to `App.vue` and it started raising error:

```
<template>
  <div> ... SOME CODE ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Editor, EditorContent } from 'tiptap'
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

ERROR

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/tiptap/dist/tiptap.esm.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (126:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     } = this.node;
|     const pos = this.getPos();
|     const newAttrs = { ...this.node.attrs,
|       ...attrs
|     };
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue 46:0-47
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Do you know what to do?

**EDIT - package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "xxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.1",
    "tiptap": "^1.32.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Vue.app` or `App.vue`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Sorry, my mistake, fixed. And I've added `npm install tiptap` line also.

Comment: Try out `sudo npm install -g vue-cli`, `vue create frontend`, `vue add vuetify` then `npm i tiptap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with webpack you need to provide more configurations, `vue create project-name` scaffolds new project to which you could add `vuetify` using

```
  vue add vuetify
```

then install `tiptap` :

```
 npm i tiptap
```

and use as explained in [official docs](https://tiptap.dev/docs/guide/installation.html#basic-usage)